# Find out type of device connected to network

Tags: c#, .net, networking

I have various devices networked: Scanner, Printer, IP Speakers, IP LED TV.

I want to determine the type of each device using C# from a list of IP Addresses, e.g.

- 192.168.1.1 is Printer
- 192.168.1.2 is LED TV
- etc

Comment: _Universal Plug n Play (UPnP)_  perhaps?

Comment: Do you want to do this as a one-time scan?  Or do you want executable that you can run anytime?

Comment: Executable that you can run anytime...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding SNMP lookups mentioned by @aliex, here is an example using [net-snmp](http://www.net-snmp.org/) interrogating a real (publicly available  on internet) host. You could do same, I expect, with C# technology.

```
snmpget -v 2c -c public     demo.snmplabs.com  SNMPv2-MIB::sysDescr.0

SunOS zeus.snmplabs.com 4.1.3_U1 1 sun4m
```

For a Linux host you get something like this :

```
Linux Foobar 2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Mar 13 00:26:49 UTC 2013 x86_64
```

For a CISCO switch something like :

```
Cisco IOS Software, C3750 Software (C3750-IPSERVICESK9-M), Version 12.2(53)SE2, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc3)
Technical Support: http://www.cisco.com/techsupport
Copyright (c) 1986-2010 by Cisco Systems, Inc.
Compiled Wed 21-Apr-10 04:49 by prod_rel_team
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods you can try. 
Every device has a MAC address. 
When a company wants to develop network connected hardware they need to apply for a range of MAC addresses they can use. 
This is information which is available. I'm not sure if there are official databases free of charge, but there should be unofficial ones. 
This will at least give you information about the manufacturer of the NIC. I don't know if you can get more detailed information.

If the devices are running SNMP and you know the SNMP community (password) you can get it that way. 
Default SNMP community is usually "public".

Even if SNMP is not active on all devices you can activate it on your network equipment, like routers to get the arp-tables which associates the IP address with the MAC address.